# Upgrade to JQuery version 3.5.0 or later on RabbitMQ

Tags: jquery, rabbitmq

i have rabbitmq in :15672 (tcp). How i can Upgrade to JQuery version 3.5.0 or later? Current version 3.4.1.
Linux \ Ubuntu server 18.
How to change javascript config (path to new scripts)?
Thank for you help!

Comment: What have you tried, and what was the error - someone might be able to help

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED!

1. Download new version JQ: https://jquery.com/download/
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vku3F.png)
2. Go to
   SERVERNAME:/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/SERVERNAME-plugins-expand/rabbitmq_management-3.8.3/priv/www/index.html and change path in index.html to you new file